# dynamic Check box android

Tags: java, android, c++, checkbox

I've created check box dynamically in a table layout. I need my first check box should be enabled at the start and rest of them should not be enabled, then if i click my first check box second CB should be enabled then so on..

**Table creation with checkbox.**

```
TableLayout ll = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablelayout22);


final TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);                       
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

tr.setId(i);                  
tr.setLayoutParams(lp);
lp.setMargins(10, -10, 15, 5);

CheckBox feature1=new CheckBox(this);
feature1 = new CheckBox(this);
feature1.setId(i);

final TextView fin = new TextView(this);
fin.setLayoutParams(lp);
fin.setText(FinancialYear1);

tr.addView(feature1);
tr.addView(fin);

ll.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

**OncheckChangedListener**:

```
feature1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
 public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (isChecked) {
        //......
    }                               
    else{


    //......
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want set first CB to true you must add follow cod:

```
boolean b = true;
feature1.setEnabled(b)
```

and with value of `b` do all you want to do,

and in continue if first you checked in `OncheckChangedListener` you must get id of CB and change the other CB with all you want to do

UPDATE /////

you have all id, so you must keep it in some list or array, and when the user hit one CB in for statement do every thing you want, i write semi code for you :

```
 for ( int i = 0 ; i < list.size ; i++)
 {
  if (!list.get(i).equal (id))
  {
    Checkbox ch = findViewByid(list.get(i);
    /// do what you want to other checkbox 
  } 
  else
     /// do what you want with checked CB
 }
```

sorry because i'm not near any IDE to test my code, sorry for code error, i hope this can help you

Comment: My first CB should be enabled at start, not checked.

Comment: what is your mean about enable?

Comment: When I check the first CB second should be enabled. default second third etc are disabled.